# Generate a tarball or (.tar.gz) of the recently modified files in the directory

Tags: shell-script, files, tar

I need a linux script that generates a tarball or (.tar.gz) of all the files in the directory passed in as an argument to the script and have been modified in the past 24 hours.

Comment: man tar. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm kind of new to Linux so I don't really know what I'm doing. I was thinking 'tar -cvf mytarfile.tar mydir/' would give me the files in the directory but I don't know how to search for the files searched in the last 24 hrs

Comment: Try to `find` them instead of searching for them then.

Answer (score 0):

[With zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
tar cf foo.tar *(m-1)
```